# Springframework build failed

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I cloned spring-framework from [official github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework).
I wanna build it to [import sources to IDEA](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/import-into-idea.md).
I go to folder spring-framework and execute

> gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava

Wrapper downloads gradle 6.6.1 and fails to build spring-core.

```
spring-framework\spring-core\src\main\java\org\springframework\core\metrics\jfr\FlightRecorderStartupEvent.java:46:
error: cannot find symbol
    @Label("Tags")
     ^
symbol:   class Label
location: class FlightRecorderStartupEvent
```

I have Windows 10 and java 8.

What`s wrong? Maybe, I need some classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the wiki-page [Build from source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Build-from-Source). It states:

> **Before You Start**
>
> To build you will need Git and JDK 8 update 262 or later. Update 262 or later is required due to the dependency on Java Flight Recorder (JFR) types. Note, however, that Oracle JDKs do not include the JFR types. Thus, we recommend an AdoptOpenJDK distribution or similar that includes the JFR types. Be sure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the jdk1.8.0 folder extracted from the JDK download.

As your build fails finding a JFR class, I assume you are not using a JDK 8 update 262 or later. You should not need to do anything else for building Spring.